# jQuery Conflicting scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a jQuery v1.11.1 linked to my webpage along with other libraries (not jQuery, but runs with jQuery) everything works fine, until i add the show/hide function. The function works fine itself, [**tested on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/devyaqoob/e2c19a9v/)

But, it stops other functions to work. So i add the `jQuery.noConflict` the results remain the same, Show/hide does not work and stops other scripts too.

**The jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".order-button").click(function() {
            $("#order-form").toggle();
            $(".order-button").hide();
        });
    });
}(jq11));
</script>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="order-button">Place Order</a>

<div id="order-form">
<h3>some contents</h3>
</div>
```

**The SCRIPTS Stops Working:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/menus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/fitvid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/portfolio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/slider.js"></script>
```

************ UPDATE ************

This fiddle has all the libraries/plugins along with the show/hide code which isn't working on the fiddle as well => **http://jsfiddle.net/devyaqoob/k3036fbv/**

Comment: Which other functions do not work?

Comment: are you loading multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: No, just the jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: @yaqoob If you expect us to help you, we need more details about your problem. Please let us know what functions do not work after the click.

Comment: @RahulDesai thanks for the reply, my problem is that when i add the show/hide function others libraries stops working, the show/hide function itself is Ok and works fine when i commented the mentioned scripts in my updated question.

Comment: What if the other scripts are (incorrectly) coded to use the `$` symbol. You do not need jQuery.noConflict unless you want to free the $ symbol.

Comment: Conflict should not occur, unless you use multiple jQuery libraries. You can use $ / jQuery keyword for the code of different plugins, wrapped in DOM ready function.

Comment: @yaqoob, Can you show complete scripting code of other plugin(s) initialization?

Comment: @ParkashKumar all the plugins initialized themself, in their own library, :( should i share all those plugins code? this will be huge mess ...

Comment: Ok, so it means you are not calling any other code except the given one?

Comment: yes, but thery are called once loaded. here's the console log
`TypeError: jQuery is not a function menus.js:124:1
TypeError: $sliders is undefined slider.js:47:1
ReferenceError: $galleryslider is not defined`

Comment: Ok, and what is the reason of using jquery-migrate.min.js?

Comment: To support older plugins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues appearing from your fiddle:

> 1 - "Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" from slider.js and
>   portfolio.js

**Reason:** jquery.browser.msie is not supported in jquery-1.9.1 version.

**Solution:** Add jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js will resolve these two.

> 2 - "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" from aniheader.js

**Reason:** Your html doesn't contain jQuery('#content-container') selector.

**Solution:** Either add html for this selector in your page or add check in plugin incase of undefined.

> 3 . "undefined is not a function" from page script toggle code.

**Reason:** jQuery initilized with jQuery keyword.

**Solution:** Replace $ with jQuery and insert this code immediately after including jQuery.

So, your view structure (html) should look like following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery conflicting script(s)</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>     

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(".order-button").click(function() {
                    jQuery("#order-form").toggle();
                    jQuery(".order-button").hide();
                });
            }); 
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/menus.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/theme.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/fitvid.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/aniheader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/portfolio.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/classie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #order-form { display: none; }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" class="order-button">Place Order</a>
        <div id="order-form">
            <h3>Place Your Order</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note: The above code is tested locally using given plugins.**

Comment: @yaqoob, consider this demo example.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is actually going some where. Now the other scripts started to work, but not the show/hide function. :( and in your fiddle there wasn't the `display: none;` css added so i did it myself.

Comment: If you have seen my tested fiddle i did the same at first, but the show/hide wasn't working, so i added the noConflict that doesn't work either. I guess i'm still at the beginning :(

Comment: My focus was to make all the plugins functional. I didn't know what other CSS / scripting code do you have. That's why I asked for the complete code.

Comment: No problem, the css part is not necessary for the example. So should i pastebin all the plugins? or just those throw error in console?

Comment: You should create a fiddle / codepin example using proper html, CSS and all other libraries to make it more clearer.

Comment: OK, i'm making a fiddle.

Comment: Let me investigate the issue!

Comment: @yaqoob: See my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the working code below. I have replaced `$` with `jq11`.

**Also**, have this jQuery code after you have included other libraries.

```js
var jq11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

jq11(document).ready(function() {
  jq11(".order-button").click(function() {
    jq11("#order-form").toggle();
    jq11(".order-button").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="order-button">Place Order</a>

<div id="order-form">
<h3>some contents</h3>
```

Comment: @yaqoob Have this jQuery code written after you have included other libraries.

Comment: Simple include of other libraries won't cause conflict, if you don't call their initializer.

Comment: @RahulDesai: `TypeError: jQuery is not a function menus.js:124:1
TypeError: $sliders is undefined slider.js:47:1
ReferenceError: $galleryslider is not defined`

Comment: @yaqoob Try the updated jQuery code in my answer above.